# Make lines in Libreoffice impress which are highlighted after clicking

Tags: libreoffice, text-formatting

I am going to be making a presentation in sometime. The presentation would have multiple lines in one page and there are going to be few pages of the presentation.

Now I want each line in a page to appear when I click Spacebar on the lappy, something like/similar to what Bradley Kuhn has done in http://meetings-archive.debian.net/pub/debian-meetings/2016/debconf16/The_Supreme_Court_of_DFSGFree.webm . I am sure there are many other examples as that presentation.

How do people do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions below were adapted for LibreOffice 5 from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=37537:

1. Make a new presentation from scratch.
2. In the `Properties` sidebar under `Layouts`, select the `Title, Content` thumbnail.
3. Enter some bullet points.
4. Select the text box that contains the bullet points.
5. Go to `Slide -> Custom Animation` in the main menu.  Click the plus sign to `Add Effect`.  Specify `Fly In` for the Entrance and press OK.

Now press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start the slide show.